# I can not modify Rules of Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I did upload an image file("icon.png").
And then I did modify Rules as a picture;
Unknown error occurs when it is saved
[Error situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjMT4.png)
I am sorry language is not english in the picture.
The error message is "Error: cannot save Rules-Unknown error occurs"

Comment: To set language of the console to English, you can add `?hp=en` to the URL. Please do this, and upload a screenshot with English language text.

Answer (score 0):

don't use .(dot) in the match statement. Instead use something like this

```
match /{imageId} {
  allow read: if imageId == 'icon.png'
}
```